# How to align a div at the bottom of another which use flex box?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to place the orange button align at the bottom of the blue one.
With my current flex code I cannot get the result wanted. Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks

```css
.content {
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.row1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.row2 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px
}

.icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="row1">
  </div>
  <div class="row2">
    <div class="icon">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .icon can't use any flex properties, since it parent doesn't have flex property

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also need to set `display: flex` on `row2` and then you can use `align-self: flex-end` on orange element.

```css
.content {
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.row1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.row2 {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px
}
.icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="row1"></div>
  
  <div class="row2">
    <div class="icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I don't want to give fixed height (in pixels) to content div?

Answer (score 4):

Here we add this css in "row 2",

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

its means if any object put at bottom then just parent block set above css and element we need to set as bottom add css "`margin-top:auto;`"

```css
.content {
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
}

.row1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.row2 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="row1">
  </div>
  <div class="row2">
    <div class="icon">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is lot of stylings that can be removed from your code if it is not required, please find it here, I have changed `.content` and `.row2` stylings

```css
.content {
    width: 350px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: flex;
}

.row1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.row2 {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100px;
    flex: 1;
    align-self: flex-end;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="row1">
  </div>
  <div class="row2">
    <div class="icon">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```